# Implementing Audacity butterworth filter in android application

Tags: java, android, android-studio, audacity

I have an android app written in java. We are recording audios and then playing them back. I need to filter the audio using butterworth filter. I tried using [JDSP](https://psambit9791.github.io/jDSP/filters.html) java filter but the results were not as satisfying as they are from using audacity software. Now I want to implement audacity butterworth filter in my android app using native c++. I found the [butterworth filter code](https://github.com/audacity/audacity/blob/master/src/effects/Biquad.cpp) but couldn't find its main file. How can I connect this with my app and how can I run this code?

Comment: You'll need to compile it into a shared library with the ndk then load that library in your application

Comment: I have never done this compiling before can you share any document on how to do it? plus what should I compile? the c++ file code ? Do I also need main function for that?